# An interesting optimization problem with a quadratic equality constraint

Tags: linear-algebra, nonlinear-optimization, matrix-calculus

I am trying to find a closed-form solution to an interesting optimization problem, which seems to be simple, but not trivial in fact. OK, here is the problem:

min$_s$  Re($v^Hs$)

s.t.      $||s||_2=1$, $s^HAs\le\epsilon$,

where Re($\cdot$) denotes the real part of a complex number, and $A$ is a positive definite matrix. The value of $\epsilon$ is between the small eigenvalue and the largest eigenvalue of $A$.

I am looking forward that someone can help me!!!!